# React Navigation v5: How to write a navigation route for a custom Navigation header button?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to add a "Gear" button on `headerRight` of Navigation header for all screens of my app. I added the button as `ScreenOptions` of `Stack.Navigator` inside a `NavigationContainer` in my `App.js` so that all `Stack.Screens` inside this Stack will have this button on header.

Now I need this button press to navigate to another screen (settingsScreen). I cannot add `navigation.navigate('settingsScreen')` onto the onPress event of the button like I do from the screens because there is no navigation prop available in the App.js file. Here is my code snippet.

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const myStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerRight: () => (
            <Button
              title='Gears'
              onPress={() => {}}   // no navigation prop available on this file
            />
          ),
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen
          name='Home'
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{ title: 'Home' }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name='Add new expense'
          component={AddNewExpense}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name='Settings'
          component={SettingsScreen}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

How can this be achieved? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have tried putting the Stack inside a "SuperStack" and passing the entire Stack.Navigator  as component of `SuperStack.Screen` just so that I can use a navigation.navigate() for the "Gear" button onPress, and it works (with now nested headers), but it feels like cheating. Is there a more react-navigation way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

screenOptions will receive the navigation prop and the route prop for each screen see [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options/#screenoptions-prop-on-the-navigator)

```js
screenOptions={({ navigation}) => ({
   //you can use navigation now
   headerRight: () => (
     <Button
     title='Gears'
     onPress={() => navigation.navigate('settingsScreen')} 
     />
   ),

})}
```